# Prepared Statement slowing down webpage

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, hibernate, prepared-statement

I have been recently upgrading a webpage hibernate based SQL connection to DB, the first thing it came to my mind was: "I should change simple 'Statement' for 'Prepared Statement' to negate SQL Injection and also, in theory, speed up the process of obtaining the data from the DB". And so I did, I changed some of the 'Statements', lets say 30% of them, have been sucessfully changed to 'Prepared Statements'. And here is the problem, now it's running really slow, I'm talking 4 minutes to do basic Selects into 4 tables, keep in mind that with 'Statements' the Select was like 200ms more or less.

I know that 'Prepared Statement' comes at its highest performance point when you use the same SQL query with diferent parameters and you keep executing it over and over. But what about when it's only used a few times only?

**My questions are:**
 "If the query is executed 3 or 4 times maximum, is it worth to change from 'Statement' to 'Prepared Statement' and why?" 
 "How can I solve the 'Prepared Statement' runing slow problem or should I go back to 'Statement'?"

I'm not sure how to tackle this problem, so any help you can provide might come in handy. Also I could provide a few lines of code if needed, to solve the problem.

DB: SQL Server 2008. 
Running: Locally (for the moment).
Local PC: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4570S CPU @ 2.90GHz 16,0 GM RAM Windows 8.1 Pro.
Software: JDeveloper 12c with the default IntegratedWebLogicServer.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

In this code there are some mixed 'Statement' and 'Prepared Statement' because I was trying to test some things out. Here is the code (Max amount I can upload):

```
    public boolean checkDate(Connection conn, String code1, String code2, String code3, String date) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    Statement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rset = null;

    boolean sampleboolean=true;
    try {

        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        stmt.execute("some sql");

        String select = "some sql"

        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(select);
        ps.setString(1, code1);     
        ps.setString(2, code2);
        ps.setString(3, code3);
        rset = ps.executeQuery();

        int countint=0;
        String codeactive="";
        while (rset.next()) {
            countint++;
            if(!codeactive.equals(""))codeactive+=",";
            codeactive+=rset.getString(1);
        }

        select = "Some sql";

        ps = conn.prepareStatement(select);
        ps.setString(1, code1);     ps.setString(2, code2);
        ps.setString(3, date);   ps.setString(4, date); 

        int count=0;
        while (rset.next()) {
            count++;
        }

        if(count==countint)sampleboolean=true;
        else sampleboolean=false;

        stmt.close();
        return sampleboolean;

    } catch (Exception e) {

        return sampleboolean;
    } finally {
        if (rset != null)
            try {
                rset.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        if (stmt != null)
            try {
                stmt.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide the code in question. Hypotheticals are nearly impossible to address, though I don't know of any reason why switching from inline to bound parameters would cause a 1200x speed decrease...

Comment: @kchason I provided some code, hopefully it helps, and I'm also confused about the why in the second part of your comment, let's hope somebody knows why.

Comment: A common problem with ORMs is that string parameters are passed as Unicode (nvarchar) instead of varchar. This prevents indexes from being used efficiently, resulting in full scans. If you are using the `jTDS` driver, add `sendStringParametersAsUnicode=false` to the connection string to avoid this problem.

Comment: @DanGuzman I'll try this out, see if it helps. Thanks.

Comment: @DanGuzman I tried adding sendStringParametersAsUnicode=false to my connection and it appear to have reduced the wait time from 3/4 minutes to 1 and a half minutes more or less. Still not the results I'm searching for.

Comment: @AlbertCorominas, the next step is query and index tuning. If you need help with that, [upload your execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) and add the link to your question.

Comment: @DanGuzman it appears that I have forgotten to close all, and when I say all I mean all, Prepared Statements. Could this be the cause of the slow loading?

Comment: @AlbertCorominas, consider using [automatic resource management](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/trywithresources-401775.html) so that you don't need to explicitly invoke `close` to clean things up. That said, I'm not sure if lack of resource disposal is the root or only cause of your performance issue. I suggest you perform the SQL tuning I mentioned and remediate the code too. Fix those individually to ascertain the performance impact.

Comment: @DanGuzman I'll try that, for a second I thought I solved the problem, but apperently it was a mistake that stopped most of the querys from executing. Feels bad man.